# Using get_theme_mod with checkbox to display content

Tags: php, functions, theme-customizer, get-theme-mod

I have a checkbox in the customizer which lets you choose to display content or not. I've got everything to work besides displaying the page content; it echoes the HTML  tags but not the WordPress dynamic page date.

```
<?php $servicescontent = get_theme_mod('services-page', 1);
$mod = new WP_Query( array( 'page_id' => $servicescontent ) ); while($mod->have_posts()) : $mod->the_post();?>
<?php $abc = get_theme_mod('services-check', 1);
if( $abc == 1) {
echo  ('<div class="section default-bg">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 id="services"  class="text-center title"><?php the_title();?></h1>
    <div class="space"></div>
    <div class="row">
      <?php the_content();?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  <!-- section end -->');}

else{
  ('');}
?>
```

Can someone tell me what characters need escaped? I am trying to teach myself through building a theme from scratch but have not been able to solve this issue myself. When looking at the rendered page's HTML, it looks like the WordPress PHP is being commented out.

Comment: Some other detailed discussion here, but keep in mind some of the code examples are incorrect... see my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22839904/how-to-get-the-values-of-wordpress-customize-checkboxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a modified version of your original code. Your echo statement isn't right and really isn't necessary. It's probably better to jump out of PHP like I've done in the code below. Also, the unnecessary `else` statement was removed:

```
<?php
$servicescontent = get_theme_mod( 'services-page', 1 );
$abc = get_theme_mod( 'services-check', 1 );
$mod = new WP_Query( array( 'page_id' => $servicescontent ) );

while ( $mod->have_posts() ) : $mod->the_post();
    if ( $abc == 1 ) { ?>
        <div class="section default-bg">
            <div class="container">
                <h1 id="services" class="text-center title"><?php the_title();?></h1>
                <div class="space"></div>
                <div class="row">
                    <?php the_content();?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- section end --><?php 
    }
endwhile;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple solution we are using in HoverCraft:

```
<?php if ( get_theme_mod( 'hovercraft_search' ) == 1 ) { ?>
```

This means "if checkbox is selected"... it's rather poorly documented, and many examples put the boolean value `0` or `1` inside single quotes which is unnecessary, because it's not a string.

Ref: https://github.com/littlebizzy/hovercraft/blob/master/template-parts/header/navigation.php

We use this to display the search icon in the header.

If you're wondering how to set a default value in your theme functions:

```
// search setting
$wp_customize->add_setting('hovercraft_search', array(
    'default' => 0,
));
```

Again, you don't need to put the default value inside single quotes in the array, because it's boolean which means it's either true or false and not an actual defined value.